# How to bypass the requirement of only one root element in a vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, css-grid

I have a case where I can't think of any other solution that would solve my problem. My task is to layout items in a css grid, those items can be either a bootstrap card or a list of cards or a list of lists...or a list of lists of lists and so on. At the end it always comes down to a card. As you probably have guessed, I need a recursion for this. So I have a card component, the code of it is not relevant for my question so I will not include it. I also have a **wrapper component** as follows

```
<template>
    <div class="container-fluid" >
        <div class="wrapper-content">
            <template v-for="item in items">
                <content-display :expand="expand" :item="item" :params="params" :param="neededParam(item.id)" :key="item.id"></content-display>
            </template>
        </div>
    </div>    
</template>
<script>

<style>
    .wrapper-content {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(9rem, 1fr));
        grid-auto-rows: auto;
        grid-gap: 1em;
    }
</style>
```

Then I also have **content display component** , which either uses a card component or a list component

```
  <template>
    <div>
        <template v-for="item in items">
            <list-component v-if="expand" :params="params" :param="param" :key="item.id" :item="item" :is="item.object_type.ModelName"></list-component>
            <object-card v-else :key="item.id" :item="item" :param="param"></object-card>
        </template>
    </div>
    
</template>
```

And finally, here's the **list component**

```
<template>
    <object-card v-if="!expand" :item="item" :param="param">
    </object-card>
    <content-display v-else :items="item.entity.list_objects" :params="params">
    </content-display>
</template>
```

My problem is with the **content display component** I need the cards to be direct children nodes of grid, however with the Vue's limitation I cannot achieve this because I need to have that outer div wrapper and so instead of this

```
<div class="container-fluid" >
        <div class="wrapper-content">
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I get this

```
<div class="wrapper-content">
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div>
                <div class="card"></div>
                <div class="card"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
            <div class="card"></div>
        </div>
```

Note: I have thought of using `style="grid-column: 1 / -1;"` on that outer div and then have another grid inside it but my generated html would be very messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Vue 3 - that [doesn't have this limitation](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/new/fragments.html#overview).

But if you use Vue 2, then try `VueFragment`

```js
const Fragments = window.VFragments
const Fragment = Fragments.VFragment

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    Fragment,
  },
})
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@superyusuke/vue-fragment@1.0.0/dist/vue-fragments.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" class="grid-container">
  <fragment>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
  </fragment>
</div>
```

You can see that the `<fragment>` is "bypassed" by the `CSS Grid`.

Comment: Although, I am getting an error "Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node." Perhaps you would know what is causing this?

Comment: @Matrix unfortunately this might happen - I read about it [here](https://github.com/Thunberg087/vue-fragment/issues/32), so there are some people who like [vue-frag](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-frag) more